# Cannot find CDN bootstrap v.2.3.2,?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I cannot find a CDN bootstrap v.2.3.2, I'm only can find Bootstrap 3.3.5. (http://www.bootstrapcdn.com/)

Do you know one?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css and https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js.

Just replace the version number in the links suggested on the main site.

Answer (score 0):

Since bootstrap is opensource on github you have all the versions here https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/releases
In case you need to download any version.